# Handle session timeout when loading data through ajax with jquery DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

My application is behind a sign in, so when loading the data through ajax, I need to verify the user still has an active session.  If the user does not have an active session, I return back with `echo json_encode(array('TIMEOUT'));` which outputs `["TIMEOUT"]`.  How do I read that response and send the user back to the sign in page?

In previous versions of DataTables, I was able to do the following:

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, result ) {
                            $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                              if(json == "TIMEOUT")
                              {
                                window.top.location.href = "/sign_out?action=to";
                                return;
                              }

                              fnCallback(json)
                            } );
```

Under DataTables 1.10, `fnServerData` has been replaced by `ajax` (see [docs](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) and [ajax.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data)).  How do I accomplish the same thing with the new DataTables version?  I feel like I am close, but it just isn't working...possible because I am doing something wrong attempting to parse the response (I never hit inside the if statement).

```
"ajax": {
        "url": "/account/location_load",
        "data": function (myJson) { 
            if(myJson == "TIMEOUT")
            {
              window.top.location.href = "/sign_out?action=to";
              return;
            }

            return myJson;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Hey @justanotherprogrammer, have deleted my answer - it should have been a comment anyway, was not that great to actual have "answer" status in my opinion :) But if your response really is `json_encode(array('TIMEOUT'))` then `if (myJson[0] == "TIMEOUT")` would be the correct answer.

Comment: I wonder if it was just something with the `data` option in DataTables that was making it not work?  Maybe in any other scenario it would have worked, I just don't know.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: Just a thought - try set `dataType : 'json'` in the ajax call ...

Comment: Good thought, but, I'm afraid it didn't make any difference.  Using `dataSrc` instead of `data` is still the only way I can get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a day and a half working on it, I finally found a working solution using `ajax.dataSrc` ([doc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc))

```
"ajax": {
        "url": "/account/location_load",
        "dataSrc": function (myJson) {

            if(myJson == "TIMEOUT")
            { 
              window.top.location.href = "/sign_out?action=to";
              return "";
            }

            return myJson.data;
          }
```

I don't know why this version allowed me to read myJson and the other didn't, but it works.  The working PHP code ended up being `echo json_encode('TIMEOUT');`

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted when you are allowed to. Perhaps this will help other people in the future.

Comment: It won't let me until tomorrow, but then I will for sure!